# Kubuntu 12.04 : starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]

Tags: graphics, driver, nvidia, xserver, ubuntu

Just after booting, while Kubuntu loads its modules and checks all of it, this message appears and the loading work stops.
[image]

As a matter of fact the Kubuntu's login screen never comes and it switches automatically on the tty1 in console mode. So I only can use the ttys 1 to 6 in console mode and the tty7 still out of order.

The following procedure to re-install the NVIDIA driver did not work :

1. Remove the existing nvidia driver :

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`
2. Upgrade to the new driver: (follow this link)

   http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-The-Latest-Nvidia-Driver-on-Ubuntu-12-04-295542.shtml

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

**Any idea ?** Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed !

As the re-installation of the nvidia `current` driver version did not work I thought to install one other version. 
This link shows how to install NVIDIA driver on ubuntu :  [BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

So I did exactly the same procedure as above but I replaced

> `nvidia-current` with `nvidia-319`.

You can access to the possible versions list with auto-completion on :

> `sudo apt-get install nvidia-`

It fully resolved my problem after **reboot**.

Afterward, I saw that the `current` version seems to be set on the `304` version but I don't know why precisely.